# Can an element's position be expressed as the position of another plus pixels?

Tags: javascript

I tried

```
document.getElementById('first').style.top = document.getElementById('second')
.style.top + 80;
```

but that doesn't seem to work. How can this be accomplished?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can do it with parsing the position and rebuilding a string with the new value and unit part string.

```
var match = document.getElementById('second').style.top.match(^(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)(.*)$);

document.getElementById('first').style.top = (parseFloat(match[1]) + 80) + match[2];
```

Comment: Bear in mind that position values can be assigned in `%`, `px`, `em`, `rem`, etc. If you always will be working in `px`, not a problem. :)

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/top

Comment: Nice code snippet Nina, I'd give you another thumb up if I could.

Comment: Funnily I have never seen this way before. It is super interesting. If you could though i would advise adding the pretty typical ways of just using element.offset or getComputedStyle ? Or i can spin up an answer too

Comment: @zfrisch, you could make an aswer, if you like.

Answer (score 1):

Nina Scholz's answer is a really wonderful way to do this. More often, in the wild, you may see two other methods. Either by using `getComputedStyle` and its `getPropertyValue` method, or most commonly by using `offsetTop` and `offsetLeft`

**Get Computed Style Example**

[Computed Style Example](https://jsfiddle.net/bzLs4gau/)

```
let div1 = document.getElementById('one');
let div2 = document.getElementById('two');

  // we use getComputedStyle to get the top and left of div1
  // we use slice to remove 'px' from the property value.

div1Top = getComputedStyle(div1).getPropertyValue('top').slice(0,-2);
div1Left = getComputedStyle(div1).getPropertyValue('left').slice(0,-2);

  //we can now manipulate the value any way we please
  //and set the values to the second div.

div2.style.top = (div1Top + 30) + 'px';
div2.style.left = div1Left + 'px';
```

**Offset Top and Left Example**

[Offset Example](https://jsfiddle.net/bzLs4gau/1/%20%22Offset%20Example)

```
let div1 = document.getElementById('one');
let div2 = document.getElementById('two');

div2.style.top = (div1.offsetTop + 30) + 'px';
div2.style.left = div1.offsetLeft + 'px';
```

Offset is more commonly used because, as you can tell, it's more readable while simultaneously being more concise.